# "If" Unexpected token. What's Wrong?

Tags: android

I've just started learning how to code using the Android Studio (the latest one), and I found an example program in the Net, but when I've pasted my code it underlines the 'if' statement as the "Unexpected token". Here's the screenshot and the code itself. What's wrong?

P.S. I am using Windows 10 (if that matters)

[Here's the screenshot :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQvAF.png)

```
public class cls {
    int a = 4;
    boolean b = a == 4;
    if (b) {
        System.out.println("It's true!");
    }
```

Comment: it should be inside some method etc

Comment: You should learn some basic java first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put operations directly in the class.
Create a constructor for your class and put your algorithm in it.

Example:

```
public class MyClass {

  int a = 4;
  boolean b;

  public MyClass() {
    this.b = a == 4;
    if (b) {
      System.out.println("It's true!");
    }
  }

}
```

=)

Answer (score -1):

Try this to expand on the comment and this method makes no sense. you cannot make an int equal a boolean. i will correct for what i think is the desired outcome

```
public class cls {

public void cls(){

}

public boolean doWork(){
    boolean result = false;
    int a = 4;
    int b = a;
    if (a == b) {
        System.out.println("It's true!");
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guys, that helped)
I'm glad to receive answers that quick :D

Comment: `boolean b = a == 4;` is perfectly legal. It will be true or false depending on `a`'s value. It may help to imagine it with (unnecessary) parentheses: `boolean b = (a == 4);`